# how can I access SVN from an Android device

Tags: android, svn, svnkit

I've been trying to use [SVN Kit](http://svnkit.com/index.html) to gain access to an SVN repository from an Android app.
Our project is supposed to check for changes to files and download them if they have changed, but still with the ability to rollback to previous versions if nessecary.

I set up a regular Java project, and had no problem using SVN Kit, I logged into the SVN server and retrived a list of the files stored there.
But when I tryed to do this from an Android project all hell broke loose. The VM run out of heap space, just trying to build it and Eclipse went down in sreaming flames mith comments like 'GC overhead limit exceeded'.
I get the impression that this is due to the diffrent type of virtural machine that Android uses, and the SVNKit jars are compiled for a diffrent type of VM.
[This Guy](http://old.nabble.com/svnkit-on-the-Android-operating-systems---some-ideas-and-hints-td24786935.html) claims to have got it working, with  what looks like an older version of Android.
Now I have suggested that we use some kind of ftp server approach, uploading new versions of the files, perhaps with seperate files containing versioning information, but I have to explore this path before I write it off as a dead end, or at least suggest that to my boss!
anyu help or suggestions would be greatly appricated.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not be directly related to SVNKit but would actually try to address the original problem.

As I understand your use-case, you want to download files if they have changed and are trying to use SVN to do this with its update command. I would rather create a simple web-service which should return me the list of files with their checksums or md5Hash. Now I am assuming that only the relevant files are present on the server. Upon receiving the hashes, you can compare them with the hashes on the device and decide to update based on any difference. This approach will work for rollback too as you need to just replace the file on the server with old file and this would be treated as a new one.

As far as heap overflow and out of memory is concerned, they are mostly because of the limited heap space around 10MB.

Answer (score 0):

I created a SVN client based on SVNKit it is available for free here : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.valleytg.oasvnlite.android

I am not sure if that will work for your purpose or you have to build your own.  If you are looking to build your own, svnkit will not work directly on the android platform.  Some of the libraries used by SVNkit are not available on the Android platform.